# MySQL: Incrementing an Integer by 1 on SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, select

Is there a way to add 1 to an integer column on the SELECT statement? Something like:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT (counter + 1) from table...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, what you have will work correctly. Did you try it?

Comment: If you mean you want to increment the actual column value in the database by the select: luckily, this is not possible.

Comment: Yes, tried it. I need the `AS` alias -- see @Michael 's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (counter + 1) AS counter FROM table;
```

Just be sure to specify a column alias `(AS counter)` or it will be more difficult to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Perfect. Worked with `AS`. Thanks @Michael!